# Raspberry Pi - C program not writing to text file

Tags: c, linux, io, raspbian

I am new to programming with linux/raspbian and I am trying to make a program that extracts the Pi system time and writes it to a text file whenever pin 23 goes high. Pin 23 is connected to an S-R Latch and pin 24 sends out a reset signal to reset the latch.

The problem I am having is that it doesn't seem to write anything to the text file that is created. The program creates the file fine but doesn't write anything to it. Here is my code:

```
using namespace std; 
FILE *f; 
struct timeval curTime;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
char dateiname[256] = "";
int i=0;
int milli;
int seconds_in_day;

wiringPiSetupGpio();

time_t t = time(0);
struct tm * now = localtime(&t);

//Create and open file
sprintf(dateiname, "/home/raspbian/Desktop/%02d%02d%02d_%02d_%02d.txt", 
                       now -> tm_year+1900, 
                       now -> tm_mon+1, 
                       now -> tm_mday, 
                       now -> tm_hour, 
                       now -> tm_min); 

f = fopen(dateiname, "w");
//write heading to file before loop
fprintf(f, "Picture, system time\n");

//Set 23 & 24 as input/ output
pinMode(23, INPUT);
pullUpDnControl(23, PUD_DOWN);
pinMode(24, OUTPUT);

while(1){ 
if(digitalRead(23)){ //If 23 is high
   i=i+1;
   gettimeofday(&curTime, NULL);
   milli = curTime.tv_usec / 1000; //Get time in milliseconds
   seconds_in_day = curTime.tv_sec % 86400; //Get seconds since midnight
   fprintf(f, "&d &d.%d\n", i, seconds_in_day, milli); //Write to file

   //send out reset signal
   digitalWrite(24, HIGH); 
   //pause for 1 second
   delay(1000);
}
}
fclose(f);
return(0);
}
```

Does anyone see any obvious errors here? I am also running the program in the terminal through

```
sudo /home/raspbian/Desktop/program
```

and just quitting the program by exiting the terminal window. Thanks

Comment: What happens if you remove the `while(1)`?

Comment: Perhaps this will help http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82952/is-it-harmful-to-close-a-terminal-window-without-properly-exiting-an-application . Depending on how you are writing your file writes, perhaps the termination of the shell results in `fclose` not getting called.

Comment: Check if fopen succeeded in opening the file by checking for a null pointer beeing returned (on failure).

Comment: @ChristophSommer removing the `while(1)` loop resulted in the system time being written once but the first fprintf statement where I write the header didn't work.

Comment: Thanks @mathematician1975 ill check it out

Comment: @user1320881 yes the file does open becase it wrote the system time when I removed the `while(1)`

Comment: comments are nice in the code, but comments in the code are not executable.  suggest posting the actual code.  Also, `sprintf()` and `localtime()` are each only called once.   They need to be called within the loop so the datainame buffer gets updated info on each iteration of the input pin controlled loop.   this line: `//Set 23 & 24 as input/ output` only needs to be performed once, before entering the loop

Comment: how is the program, when run in your terminal, expected to know about the GPIO pins on the raspbian?   suggest, when writing to the file, always end the format string with '\n' so the output gets immediately passed through the output buffer to the file

Comment: this line: `//send out reset signal to pin 24 and delay for 1 second`  should be: `//send out reset signal to pin 24. then, wait while (pin23 is high)`    this line: `//Check if 23 is high` should be: `wait while (pin23 is low)`   naturally, either of those `wait while` statements could include some delay so the CPU is not hogged by those spin loops

Comment: @user3629249 I have added the whole code, I just didn't add it earlier because some people do not like a huge chunk of code in the question and I didn't know it was relevant to the question

Comment: @user3629249 ok so the `sprintf` bit of the code also needs to be repeated in the loop? I also have \n on the end of all the `fprintf` statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably buffering the output. The buffer isn't certain to be written until the `fclose` executes, which is never.

If you want the file updated once per second with a single line when pin 23 is high, put the file `fopen` and `fclose` inside the loop.  If you want to *add* a line every second, then add `fflush(f);` after the `fprintf`.

Comment: I put in `fflush(f)` after each `fprintf` and the header does write to the text file. I am still having issues with the program not writing the system times but you have solved the original issue. Thanks

Comment: @oodan123 For one thing, the format specifier is wrong `"&d &d.%d\n"` -> "%d %d.%d\n"

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the output on pin 24 needs to be a 'short' period of 'high' to cause the latch to reset, followed by a return to 'low' in preparation for the next time the latch needs to be reset.

the lines like: `while( !digitalRead(23) );` will burn a lot of CPU cycles, so may want to put some 'delay()' or `yield()` into a body for each of those loops

```
using namespace std;
FILE *f;
struct timeval curTime;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char dateiname[256] = "";
    int i=0;
    int milli;
    int seconds_in_day;

    wiringPiSetupGpio();

    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm * now = localtime(&t);

    //Create and open file
    sprintf(dateiname, "/home/raspbian/Desktop/%02d%02d%02d_%02d_%02d.txt",
                           now -> tm_year+1900,
                           now -> tm_mon+1,
                           now -> tm_mday,
                           now -> tm_hour,
                           now -> tm_min);

    if( NULL == (f = fopen(dateiname, "w") )
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen failed for output file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    //write heading to file before loop
    fprintf(f, "Picture, system time\n");
    fflush( f );

    //Set 23 & 24 as input/ output
    pinMode(23, INPUT);
    pullUpDnControl(23, PUD_DOWN);
    pinMode(24, OUTPUT);

    // assure latch is reset
    digitalWrite(24, LOW);
    digitalWrite(24, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(24, LOW);

    while(1)
    {
        // wait while pin23 is low
        while( !digitalRead(23));

        // 23 is high
        i=i+1;
        gettimeofday(&curTime, NULL);
        milli = curTime.tv_usec / 1000; //Get time in milliseconds
        seconds_in_day = curTime.tv_sec % 86400; //Get seconds since midnight
        fprintf(f, "&d &d.%d\n", i, seconds_in_day, milli); //Write to file
        fflush( f );

        // if a latch 'set' signal is received during the following
        // three instructions, then could get locked into 
        // the while pin23 high loop

        // reset latch
        digitalWrite(24, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(24, LOW);

        // wait for pin 23 to be low
        while( digitalRead(23) );
    } // end while

    fclose(f);
    return(0);
}
```